# Select multiple display names instead of IDs using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cakephp, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a multiple select like this :

```
<select ng-model="listProds" multiple>
  <option value="10">product 1</option>
  <option value="25">product 2</option>
  <option value="35">product 3</option>
  <option value="48">product 4</option>
</select>
```

The values are the Ids for these products ( and this selectbox is generated using PHP )

& I've got this simple code in my `app.js` file :

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);
app.controller("PurchasesController", function($scope) {

    // Init products Array
    $scope.listProds = [];

});
```

When I display the `listProds` like this {{ listProds }}, I get an array containing the current selected items, but it only shows the Ids like this if I select all of them `["10","25","35","48"]`.

```
<fieldset ng-show="listProds.length > 0">
    <div data-ng-repeat="p in listProds track by $index">
        {{ p }} <!– Or –> {{ listProds[$index] }}
        <input type="text" name="pr{{ listProds[$index] }}" />
        <input type="text" name="qt{{ listProds[$index] }}" />
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

This code generate two text boxes to enter the Price and Quantity for each Product in selected from the selectbox. So instead of using `{{ p }}` or `{{ listProds[$index] }}` and displaying the Product Id, I want to display there the Product name.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create two lists: one for all your products and a separate list for the selected products:

```
$scope.listProds = [
  { key: 10, value: 'Product 1' },
  { key: 25, value: 'Product 2' },
  { key: 35, value: 'Product 3' },
  { key: 45, value: 'Product 4' }
];

$scope.selectedProds = [];
```

Now in your markup, instead of writing out each option in your select manually, you can use `ng-options` to generate your options.  Using this approach, you are basically saying that each option is an object, and you want to use the objects `value` as the display name.

```
 <select ng-model="selectedProds" ng-options="prod.value for prod in listProds" multiple>
```

Now your `$scope.selectedProds` array will contain the product objects, and not just they keys.  So now you can display the name easily:

```
<fieldset ng-show="selectedProds.length > 0">
  <div data-ng-repeat="p in selectedProds track by $index">
    {{ p.value }}
    <input type="text" name="pr{{ selectedProds[$index] }}" />
    <input type="text" name="qt{{ selectedProds[$index] }}" />
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

Not sure what your want the name attribute of the inputs to be, but I hope you get the idea.

Comment: I can't use this option because I don't know how to populate the listProds in your example, because my selectbox is filled automatically using cakePHP framework, and I've just added to it the ng-model.

Comment: Do you have access to the PHP?  Can you make a request to get a list of products, instead of having PHP generate the HTML for you?  Otherwise you will have to select DOM elements in order to get the display name, which is not the Angular way of doing things.

Comment: I thought there is another way. And yes I do have access to PHP, I guess I'll just `$http.get()` the product list

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```js
var app = angular.module('selTest', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.selectedProducts = [];
  $scope.products = [
    { id:1, name: 'POne' }, 
    { id:2, name: 'PTwo' }, 
    { id:3, name: 'PThree' }
  ];
  $scope.getNames = function(prods) {
      return prods.map(function(p) {
        return p.name;
      });
  };
  $scope.getIds = function(prods) {
      return prods.map(function(p) {
        return p.id;
      });
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="selTest">
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <select name="products" 
      class="form-control input-sm" 
      ng-model="selectedProducts" 
      ng-options="p.name for p in products track by p.id" 
      ng-style="{'width':'100%'}" multiple>
    </select>

    <div>Selected Names: {{ getNames(selectedProducts) }}</div>
    <div>Selected Ids: {{ getIds(selectedProducts) }}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks you, but the whole point was not to use the `$scope.products` array, because I don't have that. The Select multiple is generated using cakePHP, I don't know how to get it's content on an array like that.